# Capitalizing with append() function for a list

Tags: python

I'm doing homework, and I need to have my list append its variable elements so the first character is capitalized. Instead it's capitalizing all the 
characters in the elements.

```
fangs = ['facebook','apple','netflix','google'] 
upper_fang = []

for fang in fangs:
    upper_fang.append(fang.upper())

print(upper_fang)

#['FACEBOOK', 'APPLE', 'NETFLIX', 'GOOGLE']
```

The above sequence are my actual results, but I want this:

```
['Facebook','Apple','Netflix','Google']
```

Comment: have you googled "how to capitalize word in python"?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `capitalize`:

```
fangs = ['facebook','apple','netflix','google'] 
upper_fang = [] 
for fang in fangs: 
    upper_fang.append(fang.capitalize()) 

print(upper_fang)
```

Output:

```
['Facebook', 'Apple', 'Netflix', 'Google']
```

Alternatively, you can use a `list` comprehension:

```
[company.capitalize() for company in fangs]
```

Comment: Thanks this helped!